# How to fix MacBook Air '14 that won't boot

Tags: bootcamp, partition

I accidentally lost/erased all start up utilities. There used to be a Question Mark folder and was able to use the command prompts ..but no recovery utilities ever came up.. now I have a black screen and command prompts don't seem to get any response

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Tell us how did you `lost/erased all start up utilities`

Comment: Lets assume you were planing ahead and have bootable USB drive. Power on the system.
Press and hold the Option (Alt) key on the keyboard when the computer starts.
Select the USB drive as a startup disk when the option appears.
The system will start the boot process off the USB drive

Comment: What do you mean the “command prompts don’t give any response”?